# science fiction book in the future an investigator, hotel front man surgically created hermaphrodite

Tags: story-identification

An investigator is searching for murderer. At a hotel he check out there is a surgically created hermaphrodite one side of the body is male the other female, penis is in front of vagina. The hermaphrodite goes on talk show with man implanted with many vaginas on his body. Investigator has sex with him/her. On commune there is a surgically created split brain character. There is a six fingered pianist. Please help have been searching for ten years.

Comment: When was it published? Can you remember the cover, any character names etc. anything else?

Comment: Sorry no I read it a long time ago. It might have been from as early as the fifties into the eighties. I edited it some. Hope it helps

Comment: This sounds vaguely familiar and may be tied to another question I have. Was the term "Pork-you-pine" used to refer to the person with the multiple vaginas?

Comment: Not that I remember but now that I think about it, it does sound familiar, anything you might have will be welcome info. the investigator does have sex with the hermaphrodite at the hotel. The hermaphrodite is later killed.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Skin_I_Live_In  ?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's [*Crygender*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?7994) by [Thomas T. Thomas](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/thomas_thomas_t).

Excerpts from a review by [Baird Searles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baird_Searles) in *Asimov's Science Fiction*, mid-December, 1992:

> Thomas T. Thomas' *Crygender* comes equipped with a title and a cover that give one pause. The title is certainly one of the more awkwardly invented words I've run into; I initially kept trying to make it out as a combo of cryonics and gender, which even given the slightly off the wall subject matter didn't make sense. Turns out it's based on *cryptic gender*; it's the name of a major character who is a functioning, artificially produced hermaphrodite. [. . . .]
>
> The setting is early in the next century; sea level has risen and many cities are up to their second stories in water. The character Crygender has appeared more or less out of nowhere, become a media star, and has gone on to run Babylon, a sexually oriented resort on the island formerly called Alcatraz. It is handily owned by the Japanese, so is outside the jurisdiction of U. S. law.
>
> At the heart of the plot are two searches; one by an aging Frenchman, a top World Cop (U.N.), and his American liaison for a German bigwig's young and beautiful daughter whose trail leads to Babylon, and then disappears; the other by a Dutch woman whose motives we are not apprised of, who seeks employment in Babylon. The two searches inevitably cross.
>
> I enjoyed the well paced intrigue that juggles the plot elements, mixes the two searches with the mystery of Crygender's origin as well as his/her eventual demise, and revolves them all around a terrorist attack at a Netherlands airport a decade earlier. I also enjoyed Thomas's view of a flooded world, where most cities have survived with boat traffic and moving up a floor or two, still doing business as usual. [. . . .]
>
> I also wasn't much convinced by Crygender, who is described as being something like the half-man, half-woman from old freak shows, with the body divided asymmetrically into one half female, one half male, but with both sexual organs placed symmetrically and the head being a mixture of both sexes (silky mustache, lots of eyeliner, shaped brows, etc.) Sounds neither that exotic or that erotic to me. [. . . .]

Comment: Can you [edit] in why you think this?